# Estoy intentando mostrar en un JOptionPane.QUESTION.MESSAGE

Tags: java, jpa

Estoy intentando mostrar en un JOptionPane.QUESTION.MESSAGE unos valores que tengo en una tabla de una base de datos mySQL y no lo consigo. Hago la Query y la almaceno en una List pero a la hora de mostrar los valores no me sale ningún valor.Solo me sale el desplegable con el tamaño de la tabla con todos los campos vacíos. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?
El lenguaje que uso es JAVA. Soy nuevo programando.

```
public static void listaGeneros() {
    
    
    PersistenceManager.inicializar();
    Query consulta = PersistenceManager.getEntityMgr().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM generos");
    List<Genero> generos = consulta.getResultList();
    Genero[]lista = new Genero[generos.size()];
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"SELECCIONA UN GENERO","GENEROS",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,lista,lista[0]);
    PersistenceManager.finalizar();
}
```

Comment: Para agregar elementos a `List` se usa el método `add`. O sea, en vez de esto: `Genero[]lista = new Genero[generos.size()];` algo así: `lista.add(new Genero ());` pero eso es incompleto, supongo que cada instancia de `Genero` debe llenarse con los datos que vienen en la consulta, no sé si eso ya ocurre aquí: `List<Genero> generos = consulta.getResultList();` Dado que la pregunta tampoco es del todo clara, no podría ayudarte con más precisión.

Comment: Si, se supone que en la consulta es donde vienen todos los datos desde la base de datos con los que se deben llenar los campos del desplegable, o eso creo. Pero no se como añadir los datos de golpe a Genero[] lista = new Genero[generos.size()]; . Parece que es como si solo me diera la longitud del desplegable. Como deberia añadir al Array los nuevos generos?porque utilizando el metodo lista.add(new Genero()); solo añadiria un genero al Array. No?

Comment: No uso JPA, pero debería tener algún método para mapear un conjunto de resultados a una clase. Si no lo tiene tendrías que leer cada fila de la consulta, creas instancias de `Genero` con sus datos y agregarlas a la lista con `add` eso que haces de `Genero[]` y demás no sirve para este caso, como ya te expliqué en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Me podrias orientar como buscar la informacion que me comentas en tu respuesta anterior? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13012584/5587982) donde se aborda el tema sobre llenar una Entidad (que sería `Genero`)  con los resultados de una consulta. Cuando se aprende a trabajar así es más simple, porque haces la consulta y llenas la lista con los datos de la misma mapeados en instancias de la clase ´Genero`.